# Как в React, Typescript передать в зависимости от типа пропсов объект тому или иному вложенному компоненту?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня есть компонент, в который я передаю через пропсы массив объектов юнион типа:

```html
export interface IAdminInstanceFormState {
  instances: (IMaterial | IService)[];
}
```

Мне нужно в зависимости от того какого типа массив передать его дальше, тому или иному компоненту:

```html
const AdminInstanceForm: FC<IAdminInstanceFormState> = ({ instances }) => {
return (
    <div>      
        <div>
          <FormService
            service={
              instances.filter((instance) => instance.name === showForm)[0]
            }
            hideFormHandler={hideFormHandler}
          />
          <FormMaterial
            material={
              instances.filter((instance) => instance.name === showForm)[0]
            }
            hideFormHandler={hideFormHandler}
          />          
        </div>      
    </div>
  );
};
```

Я пытался сделать это через generics props, но это не помогло. Выдавал ошибку "Type 'T' is not assignable to type IService:

```html
const AdminInstanceForm = <T,>({
  instances,
}: IAdminInstanceFormState<T>): ReactElement => {
  
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState<any>(null);

  const hideFormHandler = () => {
    setShowForm(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>      
      <FormService
          service={
            instances.filter((instance) => instance.name === showForm)[0]
          }
          hideFormHandler={hideFormHandler}
      />
      <StyledButton type="button" onClick={hideFormHandler}>
        Отмена
      </StyledButton>
    </div>
  );
};
```

```html
export interface IAdminInstanceFormState<T> {
  instances: T[];
}
```

Полностью код выглядит так:

```html
const AdminInstanceForm = <T,>({
  instances,
}: IAdminInstanceFormState<T>): ReactElement => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setInstanceName(instances[0]?.name);
  }, [instances]);

  const [instanceName, setInstanceName] = useState('');
  const [showForm, setShowForm] = useState<any>(null);

  const instanceSelectHandler = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    if (showForm) {
      setInstanceName(e.target.value);
      setShowForm(e.target.value);
    } else {
      setInstanceName(e.target.value);
    }
  };

  const addInstanceHandler = () => {
    setShowForm('');
  };

  const changeInstanceHandler = () => {
    setShowForm(instanceName);
  };

  const hideFormHandler = () => {
    setShowForm(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <StyledSelect
        name="services"
        id="services"
        onChange={instanceSelectHandler}
      >
        {instances.map((instance, index) => (
          <option key={instance.name + index}>{instance.name}</option>
        ))}
      </StyledSelect>
      <StyledButton type="button" onClick={addInstanceHandler}>
        Добавить Услугу
      </StyledButton>
      <StyledButton type="button" onClick={changeInstanceHandler}>
        Изменить
      </StyledButton>
      {showForm !== null && (
        <div>
          <FormService
            service={
              instances.filter((instance) => instance.name === showForm)[0]
            }
            hideFormHandler={hideFormHandler}
          />
          <StyledButton type="button" onClick={hideFormHandler}>
            Отмена
          </StyledButton>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что вы не сможете отделить один тип от другого? Есть переменная(пропс), в нее что то попадает, typeScript'ом можно указать, что может быть несколько типов данных, typeScript будет контролировать, что бы вы не могли вызвать какое либо свойство без проверки на его существование(если свойство есть в одном типе, но нет в другом допустим или может придти массив или объект). Но вот понять, что же за тип данных пришел не получится. Только по косвенным признакам. И помните, что после компиляции, typeScript исчезает и остается только javaScript )

Comment: Надеялся, что может существует какая-то проверка вроде instanceof или typeof, которая поможет определить конкретный тип. Спасибо.